# Google maps api add marker strange behavior in IE8?

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-8

I was just playing around a bit with google maps and wanted to add a marker to the map after clicking somewhere.

This works fine, except in IE8 (the locations don't show up where i click, but a bit to the left or the right.. can't see a pattern)
This is the code:

```
            GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay, latlng) {
                map.clearOverlays();
                var marker = new GMarker(latlng);
                map.addOverlay(marker);
            });
```

The code can be found online at this location:
http://sp2hari.com/gmap/event-showinfowindow.html

if i set IE to compatilble mode, it works fine.
Anyone now hot to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that somewhere in some windows update it was fixed, because if i open the url from the opening post, it works fine, i'm not running in compatible mode, and there is no meta tag in the source.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Google Maps is not currently supported in IE8.  Are you able to use the meta tag to put your page in IE7 (compatibility mode)?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

You can find the Google Maps API issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1055&q=IE8&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal).

Comment: Yeah, that's the same i found in other resources.. Oh well, i'll make the specific page with that property then. Thanx